# How to update in twitter & Facebook from the Cocoa Mac application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, facebook, macos, twitter

I want to update my status in Facebook & twitter from inside the cocoa application.
Is this possible. IF yes how to do?

Comment: Have you Googled your question? Google always returns something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For twitter MGTwitterEngine
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

For Facebook use there API 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: He was talking about Cocoa/MacOS not CocoaTouch/iOS

Answer (score -4):

In facebook it would be:

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'message');
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

you would have to google for twitter's api.

Comment: What language is that? The question is tagged "Cocoa" and "Objective-C".